# CartesianChart (Live-Charts) doesn't work with DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, livecharts

I use LiveChart Library and I have a problem to show charts. Indeed, in my window, I want many charts with many types, so I use a DataTemplateSelector, link to a class for each type of chart. But, when the chart appears, there is no data on it. I tried to add `DataContext="{Binding}"` in the declaration of my "Column Graph" but without success.

Here's an extract of my code:

ResultView.xaml

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="graphEmptyTemlpate">
            <StackPanel Width="Auto" Height="60" Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="700">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"  FontSize="20" Margin="0,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF006B93"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="columnTemplate">
            <StackPanel Background="#FFBFBFBF">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding subTitle}"/>
                <lvc:CartesianChart Width="400" Height="400" Series="{Binding listSeries}">
                </lvc:CartesianChart>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <local:GraphTemplateSelector
        ColumnTemplate="{StaticResource columnTemplate}"
        GraphEmptyTemplate="{StaticResource graphEmptyTemlpate}"
        x:Key="graphTemplateSelector" />

    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Results}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Expander Header="{Binding Title}"
                              IsExpanded="True"
                              Margin="10 10 10 10"
                              FontSize="20"
                              Foreground="White">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                                        ItemTemplateSelector="{DynamicResource graphTemplateSelector}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel Margin="10 10 10 10" Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

the constructor of my ViewModel class is in ResultViewModel.cs
In the xaml, Results corresponds to Results in c#, Items corresponds to RpAgitation.Items in c#

```
public ResultsViewModel()
{
    instance = this;
    this.Results = new ObservableCollection<ResultParts>();
    this.RpAgitation = new ResultParts("Results of the Agitation part");

    ColumnGraph gr = new ColumnGraph();
    RpAgitation.Items.Add(gr);

    this.Results.Add(_rpAgitation);

}
```

and finnaly the ColumnGraph.cs

```
public class ColumnGraph : IGraph
{
    public SeriesCollection listSeries { get; set; }

    public ColumnGraph()
    {
        listSeries = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new LineSeries
            {
                Title = "Series 1",
                Values = new ChartValues<double> { 4,7,8,9,5,4,2}
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Thanks for opening the issue in the repo, I will fix it asap

Comment: this is already fixed since 0.7.7 version

Answer (score 1):

Currently SeriesCollection class in not a WPF UiFramework element, I really didn´t want to, but I guess we need t do it to avoid this issue.

I am not sure if this is a bug with WPF, or just we are doing thing wrong.

any ways, I will investigate further, for now an alternative is to try this syntax:

```
DataSource = new List<ChartValues<double>>
        {
            new ChartValues<double> {r.Next(0, 10), r.Next(0, 10), r.Next(0, 10)},
            new ChartValues<double> {r.Next(0, 10), r.Next(0, 10), r.Next(0, 10)},
            new ChartValues<double> {r.Next(0, 10), r.Next(0, 10), r.Next(0, 10)}
        };

        DataContext = this;
```

And The XAML

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <lvc:CartesianChart Height="400">
                        <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
                            <lvc:LineSeries Values="{Binding}"></lvc:LineSeries>
                        </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
                    </lvc:CartesianChart>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```